# Having an issue with a JS Hamburger Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Added a Hamburger Menu to our site. There are no console log errors and the menu refuses to expand.

The page in question - https://www.harpercollege.edu/foundation/alumni-dev/index.php

The Code Pen I'm working from - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vQNmgx

Everything works fine in codepen and visually it looks fine in the live site. I just can click or expand. The goal is to be able to expand the menu and push over the rest of the page.

{HTML}

```
<body>
    <nav class="side-nav hidden">
        <div>
            <div class="open-menu-side" id="side">
                <button class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze" type="button">
                  <span class="hamburger-box">
                    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                  </span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <ul class="side-nav-ul">
                <a href="#"><li class="block">Home</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="block">Profile</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="block">Blogs</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="block">Following</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="block">Settings</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="block">Logout</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header id="pushed">
        <nav>
            <div class="open-menu" id="main">
                <button class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze" type="button">
                  <span class="hamburger-box">
                    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                  </span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="brand">Login!</div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section></section>

  <p class="hello-text">hello</p>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

{JS}

```
$(".hamburger").on("click", function(){
    $(".hamburger").toggleClass("is-active");
  $('body').toggleClass('menu-active');
    $(".side-nav").toggleClass("hidden");
    if($("#side").hasClass("is-active")){
        $("#main").toggleClass("hidden");
    } else if(!$("#side").hasClass("is-active")) {
        $("#main").toggleClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

{CSS}

```
html,body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
button:focus {outline:0;}
a{
  color: #fff;
}
a:hover{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.side-nav{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
}
.open-menu-side{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
.side-nav-ul{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
}
.block{
  height: 40px;
}
header{
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.brand{
  display: inline-block;
}
.img-menu img{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  float: left;
}
.hidden{
  position: absolute;
  right: -300px;
}
#pushed{
  position: relative;
}
#main{
  float: right;
}
.hamburger {
  padding: 15px 15px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-property: opacity, filter;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-transform: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible; }
  .hamburger:hover {
    opacity: 0.7; }

.hamburger-box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; }

.hamburger-inner {
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px; }
  .hamburger-inner, .hamburger-inner::before, .hamburger-inner::after {
    width: 40px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 0.15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease; }
  .hamburger-inner::before, .hamburger-inner::after {
    content: "";
    display: block; }
  .hamburger-inner::before {
    top: -10px; }
  .hamburger-inner::after {
    bottom: -10px; }


.hamburger--squeeze .hamburger-inner {
  transition-duration: 0.075s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19); }
  .hamburger--squeeze .hamburger-inner::before {
    transition: top 0.075s 0.12s ease, opacity 0.075s ease; }
  .hamburger--squeeze .hamburger-inner::after {
    transition: bottom 0.075s 0.12s ease, transform 0.075s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19); }

.hamburger--squeeze.is-active .hamburger-inner {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition-delay: 0.12s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1); }
  .hamburger--squeeze.is-active .hamburger-inner::before {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: top 0.075s ease, opacity 0.075s 0.12s ease; }
  .hamburger--squeeze.is-active .hamburger-inner::after {
    bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transition: bottom 0.075s ease, transform 0.075s 0.12s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1); }
.hello-text{
  text-align: right;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
}
body.menu-active{
  padding-right: 300px;
}
```

Comment: To push over the rest of the page it would be best to have the hamburger menu container and a page container as separate children of the body tag. If this isn't possible you can position them both absolutely, but this route would require explicit instructions on the animation of the menu to move them both over `x` amount.

Comment: Did you know you are loading jquery twice, each time a different version from a different CDN.  You also have HTML code in the head section which is not going to work.

Comment: you should add ```body{overflow-x: hidden}``` so you don't get that horizontal scrollbar and it hides the menu from sight. Also, since you are positioning the menu ```absolute```, you would need to move the body to left 300px when you do your animation. Absolute will make it go over the top of the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put the script which adds the click handler in your document's `head`. At the point that the script is loaded, `$('.hamburger')` doesn't exist in the DOM, so the click handler is not added, therefore the clicks have no effect.

To fix, consider moving the script to the bottom of the page, or wrapping it in [`$(document).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: That was exactly it! Didn't have to change a single additional thing. Thank you so much! I feel like a total airhead though...